# SSRS count of rows within each group

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, grouping, ssrs-tablix

I have a report that will show several groups of details records on the page. I would like to order them so that the groups with more rows are first. Does anyone know what formula should show me the details row count per group? I tried `=CountRows(MainGroup)` but that errored.

[image: design view]

[image: output with row count]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include a scope name in any expression, it has to be enclosed in quotes and is case sensitive, so in your case it's just a case of adding the quotes...

```
=CountRows("MainGroup")
```

Note: If the expression sits in the "MainGroup" row(s) anyway, then there is no need to specify the scope so `=CountRows()` would return the same results as when no scope is specified, the current scope is used.